# Convert 1D String array to 2D String array

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I have this String array:

```
String[] spltstr = {"a","b","c","d","e","f",...,"z"};
```

And I need to place every value there into an array like this:

```
String[][] matrix;
```

I know the dimensions of both arrays, and as an output I need my matrix to look like:

```
matrix={{"a","b","c","d","e","f"},
        {"g","h","k","l","m","n"},
        {...................."z"}};
```

Can you tell me if this is possible? 
I'm having problems since the dimension of the first array is "n" and the second array is an "m"x5.

If you think there is a better way to get this done I would be thankful.

Comment: Yes, its possible. Give t a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible.

Think about the mapping.

```
n  (i,j)
0->(0,0)
1->(0,1)
2->(0,2)
3->(0,3)
4->(0,4)
5->(1,0)
6->(1,1)
7->(1,2)
```

etc...

So the idea is to transform n into a pair of (i,j)

Comment: Thanks, I created a function that does the next: 

`for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {`

   `for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++) {`

    `matrix[i][j]=spltstr[index];`

    `index++;`

   `}`

  `}`

I set my index to 0 before the loops but it still returns an  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and I can't see why, any idea?

Comment: `index` is likely going out of range. If the array is a rectangle and there are 6 columns then in order to fit 26 characters you need 5 rows. This gives 30 slots. That would force `index` out of `spltstr` valid range. Another possibility is that you have accounted for that and built a jagged array with the last row not having as many cells. Then `matrix[i][j]` could be out of range because the inner for loop always references the length of the first row of the matrix.

Comment: Yes, in fact I found that my index was growing faster than the `i` and `j` counters, I solved this by adding `if(index<spltstr.length) ` this way I make sure `index` variable won't go out of range. Thanks for your help @bombe

Answer (score 0):

well, if you know the sizes of the array, you can write a while loop to populate matrix.

Have 3 variables outside the loop called Row, and Col, and Out. You know that there are X letters per row. So you check in your while loop if you have populated the (X-1)th index of matrix, you update row to row++, and col to 0. Each iteration of the loop, you'll do Col++, as well as Out++.

Because Row and Col and Out are being updated, you can just set matrix[Row][Col] to equal spltstr[Out].

You'll finish the problem once you run out of letters in the alphabet.